# Strange Property Override in DataGridViewTextBoxCell

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, properties, overriding, reflector

If you look at the DataGridViewTextBoxCell property, ValueType, in reflector, you can see it overrides a property from DataGridViewCell.

The strange thing is, is that the overriden property is readonly, but the property in the parent class is read and write.

I can only presume that the property has been shadowed and reflector doesn't ...erm .. reflect this.

Is this right?

eta: I'm looking at the source, in reflector, as vb.net.

Answer (score 1):

The CLR implements properties internally as methods. There will be one method for each acessor. So if your property is read/write, you will have two methods. If your method is read-only or write-only, then you will have only one method.

You can see that for yourself using Reflector if you choose IL instead of Visual Basic.

```
.method public hidebysig specialname virtual instance class [mscorlib]System.Type get_ValueType() cil managed
```

If you comapre with the ToString method...

```
.method public hidebysig virtual instance string ToString() cil managed
```

... you will note that both start with ".method".

Since you have two methods, you can override them independently one from another.

Comment: I never realized it was possible to override only one of the accessors... that's good to know ! However, I find it rather confusing, because the overridden property seems to be read-only even though it's not...

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. I understand that a property declaration is translated into 2 methods but, in vb.net at least, it's not possible to override a read and write property and just override the get - at least not without the shadows keyword.

Comment: Yeah.. You're right. Yesterday I tested it with C# and since it worked I assumed it would work on VB.NET too. Now I tried it on VB.NET but haven't found a way to make it work. The workaround would be to put a setter that accesses the base setter.